# Placing custom markup by dbId not showing the markups on viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

So I want to reproduce [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/placing-custom-markup-dbid) tutorial. I have got the exact same code for the IconMarkupExtension.js . But I do not get the markups on the viewer but custom extension gets added to the tool bar with the icon. I  was wondering if it has to do with the model I'm using but not sure.

My Viewer Code

```js
if (viewer != null) {
    var thisviewer= viewer;
    if (thisviewer) {
      thisviewer.tearDown();
      thisviewer.finish();
      thisviewer= null;
      $("#forgeViewer").empty();
    }
  }
 
  var options = {
    env: 'AutodeskProduction',
    api: 'derivativeV2',
    getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
      var token = accessToken;
      var timeInSeconds = 3600; 
      onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
    }
  };

  var documentId = "urn:" + urn;

  Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {

    var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
    var startedCode = viewer.start();
    if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
    }
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
  });
```

extension loading

```js
  viewer.loadExtension('IconMarkupExtension', {
    button: {
        icon: 'fa-thermometer-half',
        tooltip: 'Show The Temperature'
    },
    icons: [
      { dbId: 69, label: '300&#176;C', css: 'temperatureHigh fas fa-thermometer-full'},
      { dbId: 70, label: '300&#176;C', css: 'temperatureHigh fas fa-thermometer-full'},
      { dbId: 71, label: '300&#176;C', css: 'temperatureHigh fas fa-thermometer-full'}
    ],
    onClick: (id) => {
      console.log(' ======================= IconMarkupExtension onClick id: ' + id);
        viewer.select(id);
        viewer.utilities.fitToView();
        switch (id){
            case 69:
                alert('Sensor offline');
        }
    }
})
```

This is [the](https://viewer.autodesk.com/preview/id/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90MTYyOTEyNTU1MDk0Ml9iYTYzZjEyZi1jMjFhLTQ5ZTgtODFkOC1mNDNiMzBiMDVlMjNfMTYyOTEyNTU1MjQyNy5pZmM?sheetId=ZDVjZGQyNmQtOWI5Ni00NjA3LWIwNWQtNGFkY2JiMjg0ODRj) model I'm using.

I'm using viewer version V7*

Thank you

EDIT :

I managed to get the icons but all the icons are displayed centered .  as you see below
[image: Centerd Icons]

it is the same even if i selected one particular object .

[image]

labels and values shows correctly according to the model ID that I have added .

Is it something to do with the models I have ?

Comment: Any message on console?
You can also check if the availability of the current dbIds (viewer.isolate() method can help)

Comment: Hi @JoãoMartins , nope no messages on console . Yeah  I print the dbids before isolating/selecting so the Ids are available.

Comment: have u added script for fontawesome to load fa fa ??

Comment: Hi @RonakShethia , Yes I have included the script , tried both locally and public css as well

Comment: @JoãoMartins any idea about this scenario ? or can you reffer anyone else to check with ?? thank you

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay, adding a detailed answer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://forgeplant.herokuapp.com) you can find a sample implementing this extension.

Please note that to make it work, you need to add the [extension](https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-plant-operation/blob/master/forgeSample/wwwroot/js/iconExtension.js), [styles](https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-plant-operation/blob/master/forgeSample/wwwroot/css/index.css#L15-L44), reference [css](https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-plant-operation/blob/master/forgeSample/wwwroot/index.html#L14) and [js](https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-plant-operation/blob/master/forgeSample/wwwroot/css/index.css#L15-L44), [add it to viewer](https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-plant-operation/blob/master/forgeSample/wwwroot/js/forgeViewer.js#L25-L44), and ensure the dbids specified are present in your model.
[Here](https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-plant-operation) is the source for the sample

Comment: Hi @JoãoMartins , thank you I managed to get it work . issue was I have not added css for the label . thank you very much 
Cheers

Comment: Hi  @JoãoMartins, I have edited my original question

Comment: Dont mind my Edit  @JoãoMartins,  it has to with the model I'm using . ayour answer works perfectly fine. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad it helped! :)